# how to upload nodejs app with socket to heroku?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, websocket, socket.io

I did upload to heroku app with nodejs & socket
https://github.com/Victor-Nikiforov-Web/OnlineChat-React-hooks
but the socket don't respond

Comment: Is it working locally?

Comment: yes , locally its work

Comment: I would check out the docs https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets. Ensure you are running heroku features:enable http-session-affinity

Comment: I did run this feature

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a Procfile with "web: node app.js" ?